# How can I compare two lists, and find the difference between them?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program which will print which cars went to fast, and which cars didn't. The input is like this.
1   12:00:03    DX-89-EH
2   12.00.42    DX-89-EH
This list consists of a very large number of number plates, so I want to split these in two groups. One for sensor one, and one for sensor two. Afterwards I want to compare the times, and calculate the difference between them. I can then calculate the final speed. Thus far I came with this:

```
    distance = 200

def speed(line):
    max_speed = line
    print(max_speed)


def line_information(line):
    sensor, time, plate = line.split()
    return {"sensor": sensor, "time": time, "plate": plate}


data = []
file = open('traffic_input.txt').read().split('\n')
for counter, line in enumerate(file):
    if counter == 0:
        speed(line)
    else:
        data.append(line_information(line))



def elapsed_time(time_start, time_end):
    hours, minutes, seconds = time_start.split(":")
    time_start_sec = int(hours) * 3600 + int(minutes) * 60 + int(seconds)
    hours, minutes, seconds = time_end.split(":")
    time_end_sec = int(hours) * 3600 + int(minutes) * 60 + int(seconds)
    elapsed_time = time_end_sec - time_start_sec


def speed(kmh):
    actual_speed = (distance / elapsed_time) * 3.6


file = open('traffic_input.txt').read().split('\n')
for counter, line in enumerate(file):
    if counter == 0:
        speed(line)
    else:
        line_information(line)
```

Can someone please explain what I can do to make this work, and how I can compare the lists?
Thanks in regards.

Comment: May I point you to [the `difflib` docs from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in base python, but if you're doing a bigger project, I highly recommend using statistical packages (specifically `numpy` and `pandas`) to do this. This is because as your dataset grows, numpy and pandas store data in a much more efficient way than base python. (see [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/introduction-data-science-numpy/) for more information).

Using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

fullTime= []
file = open('traffic_input.txt').read().split('\n')
for counter, line in enumerate(file):
        data.append(line_information(line))

#create dataframe
data= pd.DataFrame(fullTime)

#split columns into starting time (sensor 1), ending time (sensor 2), and license plate
data["startingTime"] = data[fullTime].split()[1]
data["endingTime"] = data[fullTime].split()[4]
data["licensePlate"] = data[fullTime.split()[2]

#use elapsed time function to create a new column in the dataframe with elapsed time
data["elapsedTime"] = elapsed_time(data["startingTime"], data["endingTime"])
```

Some helpful links about pandas:

- [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html)
- [getting started tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/05_add_columns.html)
- [python for data analysis book](https://wesmckinney.com/book/)

If you have a reason to be absolutely married to base python, comment and I'll edit. But for most data analysis tasks, python libraries make your life way easier (even if they take a little bit of time to learn up front).

Edit since you're tied to base python:

I would approach this by using a list of lists with the format `[[starting time, endingtime, elapsed time][starting time for car 2, ending time for car 2, elapsed time for car 2], ...]`, like so

```
timeArr = []
for i in data:
    thisRow = [];
    startingTime = i[fullTime].split()[1]
    endingTime = i[fullTime].split()[4]
    thisRow.append([startingTime, endingTime, elapsed_time(startingTime, endingTime)
```

After this, you can access the elapsed time for every license plate by using

```
for i in timeArr:
    print(i[2])
```

You could even add the license plate number to part of the original array if you wanted some kind of ID to access it with.

Comment: Hi @luke, thank you so much for your explanation. Unfortunately, I'm tied to base python. Do you think you can help me with that?

Comment: @Hoi2022 edited. The code I wrote is essentially what pandas would do, but in a more verbose and less efficient way. I'm just curious, why are you tied to base python?